# Haskell arbitrary typeclass instance return type

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

From the Haskell Book chapter on Monoids, I am writing quickcheck tests for

```
semigroupAssoc :: (Eq m, S.Semigroup m) => m -> m -> m -> Bool
semigroupAssoc a b c =
    (a S.<> (b S.<> c)) == ((a S.<> b) S.<> c)

type IdentAssoc = Identity String -> Identity String -> Identity String -> Bool
```

, invoking with

```
quickCheck (semigroupAssoc :: IdentAssoc)
```

Here is the arbitrary typeclass instance

```
instance (Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary (Identity a) where
    arbitrary = do
        a <- Test.QuickCheck.arbitrary
        return (Identity a)
```

My question is that in my arbitrary instance, I can return either (Identity a) or just a.  (Identity a) is correct, but just a gives no compiler error and causes an infinite loop when run. Why is this?

Comment: Because you simply call the same function again.

Comment: Which function am I calling again?

Comment: the one you have just defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type inference changes the `arbitrary` call to point at the *same* instance we are defining right now, causing an infinite loop.

```
instance (Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary (Identity a) where
   arbitrary = do
        x <- Test.QuickCheck.arbitrary  -- this calls arbitrary @ a
        return (Identity x)

instance (Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary (Identity a) where
   arbitrary = do
        x <- Test.QuickCheck.arbitrary  -- this calls arbitrary @ (Identity a)
        return x
```

Every time we call a class method, the compiler infers which instance to call.

In the former case, the compiler infers `x :: a` (only this type makes the code type check!), hence it calls `arbitrary @ a`.

In the latter case, the compiler infers `x :: Identity a` (only this type makes the code type check!), hence it calls `arbitrary @ (Identity a)`, causing the infinite loop.

Comment: Excellent, was right in front of me; thanks for the help.

Comment: Doesn't this change the return type, though? Why wouldn't the compiler catch it?

Comment: @tesserakt I hope my last edit clarifies this a bit.

Answer (score 4):

If you write it as:

```
instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (Identity a) where
    arbitrary = do
        x <- arbitrary
        return x
```

(I renamed `a` to `x` to cause less confusion).

Then Haskell will do the type plumbing, and it will derive that, since you write `return x`, `x` must have type `Identity a`. And we are lucky, since there exists an `arbitrary :: Arbitrary a => Gen a`, the one we just defined (put in boldface here).

So that means that we have constructed an infinite loop. For instance in Java, it would look like:

```
public int foo(int x) {
    return foo(x);
}
```

Of course we can define such a function, and it is correct if we check the types. But there is of course no progress, since we keep calling the same function that will again call that function and again, and again,...

If you however write:

```
instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (Identity a) where
    arbitrary = do
        x <- arbitrary
        return Identity x
```

Haskell will derive that `x` has type `a`. And we are again lucky, since we have defined that `Arbitrary a` should hold, some somewhere there is an `arbitrary :: Arbitrary a => Gen a` function, but it is a different one (that's why I did not write it in boldface here), and that one will generate the value that we wrap in the `Identity` constructor.

Note that in the **first example, we do not even have to add the `Arbitrary a` constraint**: indeed:

```
instance Arbitrary (Identity a) where
    arbitrary = do
        x <- arbitrary
        return x
```

this compiles just fine, since we never generate an arbitrary `a`.